# how to confirm to the data inserted in sqlite database or not in php

Tags: php, sqlite

i am new in php. i am trying to inset the data in sqlite database and my code is

```
          $query= $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO favorite_apps(version, apppkgname, appname, appdescriptive, appClass, applink, place) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $query->bindParam(1,$Version);
            $query->bindParam(2,$Package);
            $query->bindParam(3,$AppName);
            $query->bindParam(4,$AppDescription);
            $query->bindParam(5,$ClassName);
            $query->bindParam(6,$AppLink);
            $query->bindParam(7,$Place);
            $res = $query->execute();
```

but i am getting null in $res, so how to confirm the data is inserted or not in sqlite database

thanks

Answer (score 0):

PDO's execute method returns either true or false, so there must be a problem in your php code...
Try using `$query->debugDumpParams();` to output the prepared query and test it.

Comment: my code is running properly, but  "$res = $query->execute();" does not return true,if data is added or false if not added

Comment: yes i have used PDO as $dbh= new PDO($dir) or die("cannot open the database"); where $dir  is path of my db

Comment: sqlite ignores meaningless whitespace such as this